# Question about consumer report and market shares

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, marketing, inference

in my job we just got a consumer report about the automotive industry in which they outline the most significant brand attributes considered in the process of purchasing a new car.

I transformed the presentation into a table like this:

```
Brands   Attribute.1    Attribute.2    Attribute.3   ...
Brand.A       0.23             0.21             0.06
...
```

I also happen to have the market share by brand, which is an ordered data frame of brand names and market shares.

What I want to know is which brand attributes can actually predict market share. I know should have time series data to make a robust analysis but I only have one period data and would like to know if I can make an approximation with this imperfect data.

How can I measure the attribute's effect on the share's variance? What other alternatives with my current data do I have if I get a non-significant result?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to mimic the algorithm used for "Analyze Key Influencers" in Data Mining Add-in for Excel. First, it converts quantitative predictors into qualitative by defining some ranges by quantiles. Then it trains a Naive Bayes classifier. Model parameters can be interpreted as the influence rates. I'm sorry this answer does not give implementation in R, but you should be able to reproduce it with `e1071` package.

- [Analyze Key Influencers (Table Analysis Tools for Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282341.aspx)
- [Microsoft Naive Bayes Algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174806.aspx)